# Adding colour filters in a shiny application

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following shiny app working with the titanic_train dataset (library(titanic))

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)

#Label as factors
titanic_train$Survived <- as.factor(titanic_train$Survived)
titanic_train$Pclass <- as.factor(titanic_train$Pclass)
#Check of ze een title hebben
titanic_train$Man <- ifelse(titanic_train$Embarked %in% c("S"), 1, 0)

setwd("")

UI <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Visualizing results of the titanic: "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     selectInput("dataset", "Pick the dataset:",
                choices = unique(titanic_train$Man)),
     selectInput("dimension", "Pick the x-axis:",
                choices = c("Sex", "Pclass"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
 )
)

Server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered_titanic <- reactive({
    titanic_train %>%
      filter(Man == input$dataset)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_titanic(), aes_string(x="Age", y=input$dimension, colour = "Survived")) + 
      geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

This works but what I actually want to do is to show the whole dataset with colour filter, like:

```
ggplot(filtered_titanic(), aes_string(x="Age", y=input$dimension)) + 
          geom_point()
```

And then when I select a value in the inputbox (input$choices) put a colour filter on it. So when I fe select: "Survived" the function should become:

```
ggplot(filtered_titanic(), aes_string(x="Age", y=input$dimension, colour="Survived")) + 
          geom_point()
```

So basically I should have three options in the filter box ->

- Plot without any filter
- Plot with filter - Survived
- Plot with filter - Pclass

I tried this with adding ""  to the input measures but then I still see colour popping up. Any thoughts on how should do this as a best practise?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this does what you want, or can help you in the right direction. I added an input for determining what variable to color by, and an `if else` to return `NULL` as color if the user does not select a variable.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)

#Label as factors
titanic_train$Survived <- as.factor(titanic_train$Survived)
titanic_train$Pclass <- as.factor(titanic_train$Pclass)
#Check of ze een title hebben
titanic_train$Man <- ifelse(titanic_train$Embarked %in% c("S"), 1, 0)

setwd("")

UI <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Visualizing results of the titanic: "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Pick the dataset:",
                  choices = unique(titanic_train$Man)),
      selectInput("dimension", "Pick the x-axis:",
                  choices = c("Sex", "Pclass")),
      selectInput("my_color", "Pick the colour:",
                  choices = c("None","Survived", "Pclass"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered_titanic <- reactive({
    titanic_train %>%
      filter(Man == input$dataset)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_titanic(), aes_string(x="Age", y=input$dimension, 
      colour = if (input$my_color!="None") input$my_color else NULL)) + 
      geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

[image]

Hope this helps!